# Can I load content from user in Spring Boot (not in header)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I  making  Spring Boot application and I need to load content from user (I don't want to use header to this). Is this possible? If yes which library I need?I creating app for the rental(it's not real rental) and I need to get information if someone want to rent something. I'm new in Spring Boot, so please don't hate me for this question.

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean by "content from user" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what are you saying. You don't want to send user's data in url ? Like using path or parameter variables ? example http://rent/user?username=fo&email=bar. Well you should use POST method and load user' data in payload. More info I can't tell you because I don't know what architecture your back-end use. It's an MVC or REST app ? 
Here are some sources : 
mvc  : https://tutorial.techaltum.com/MVC-Get-Post.html 
rest : https://dzone.com/articles/simple-spring-boot-post 
Next time try to be more specific :)